# How to hide navbar header in login page in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have header component,and 2 pages and one signin page.Using _app.js overided app.js so that I can have header in all pages.I have 2 issues :-

1) In signin page header appears .I don't know how to hide it in _app.js.

2) On _app.js load I have to check local storage for identifying whether user is already logged in if not it must redirect to signin page .

For 2 problem one thing I can do is in signin component check local storage onComponenDidMount() method and based on local storage redirect the page.

layout.js

```
class Layout extends Component {
    render() {
        const { children } = this.props
        return (
            <div className='layout'>
                <Header />
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

_app.js

```
export default class MyApp extends App {
    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
        return (
                <Layout>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>
        )
    }
}
```

signin.js

```
class Signin extends Component {
 handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(users.username ===document.getElementById('username').value && users.password=== document.getElementById('password').value){
            localStorage['username']=users.username;  
            Router.push({ pathname: '/appUser' });                
                message.success('Login SuccessFull');            
        }else {
            message.error('Wrong Email and Password');
        }
      };

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="form-container">
                <div className="form-content">


               <Form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit} className="form"  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                   <div className="logo-section">                            
                       <img src="../../static/images/logo.png" ></img>                            
                       <div >
                           <h3 className="bold">Homelife</h3><h3>Care</h3>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <Form.Item>
                        <Input id="username" placeholder="User name" />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item >
                        <Input.Password id="password" placeholder="password"/>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ span: 12, offset: 5 }}>
                        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" >
                             SIGN IN
                        </Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Please help
```

Answer (score 16):

If anyone is facing the same problem with functional components this might help.

You can use `useRouter()` from `next/router`.

To access the path use `router.pathname` which provides the current path. This will work even if we refresh the page and not only when the route is changed like in @Krazy's solution.

```
const router = useRouter();
const showHeader = router.pathname === '/login' ? false : true;
return (
    {showHeader && <Header />}
    <Component {...pageProps} />
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done that.. I'm listening to router event and based on that I'm showing header and

```
class Layout extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
        this.state={
            showHeader:false,
            loading:true
        }    
        this.routeChangeHandler=this.routeChangeHandler.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete',this.routeChangeHandler);

    }
    routeChangeHandler(url){
        console.log(url);
        if(url==='/signin'){
            this.setState({showHeader : false});
        } else{
            this.setState({showHeader:true});
        }

    }
    render() {
        const { children } = this.props
        return (
            <div className='layout'>
                 {this.state.showHeader ? 
                <Header />: ''}
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Check Local storage whether user already logged  or not in the _app.js

```
_app.js

 componentDidMount(){

        if(constlocalStorage.getLocalStorage()){
            Router.push({pathname:'/appUser'});
        } else{
            Router.push({pathname:'/signin'});
        }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide Navbar for a certain page by checking the if the url in the window urlBar matches the url of the page you want to hide the navbar for.
This can be done like this

```
const showNavbar =  window.location.href === 'http://localhost:3000/login' ? false : true;
return (
    {showNavbar && <Navbar />}
    {children}
);
```